# add firewall rules using sed in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have to add some firewall rules in my script. The rules must be written in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

I try to use `sed` for this operation but it doesn't work:

```
sudo sed -i '/:OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW - [0:0]/a \
-A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53248 -j ACCEPT \
-A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 50825 -j ACCEPT \
-A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20048 -j ACCEPT \
-A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT \
-A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT' /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

I try to add the rules after the line `:OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW - [0:0]` which is in the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

There is happening anything. The `iptables`-file has the same content as before. The new lines aren't added.

What am I doing wrong?

Content of iptables (before and after the executing `sed`-command)

```
...
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
...
```

Expected output:

```
...
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :DOCKER - [0:0]
    :OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW - [0:0]
    -A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53248 -j ACCEPT
    -A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53248 -j ACCEPT
    -A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53248 -j ACCEPT
    -A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53248 -j ACCEPT
    -A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
    ...
```

Comment: Lol at testing sed code with `-i` option. Also what error do you get, what does `it doesn't work:` mean?

Comment: Only added it here. Testing without -i so I see the output directly.

Comment: You need to show us a sample of input and expected output, otherwise we cannot reproduce or solve your issue. You also need to make it clearer what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: I've added the additional information. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this line,

```
/:OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW - [0:0]/a
```

to

```
/:OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW - \[0:0\]/a
```

In a regular expression, square brackets are used to indicate character classes, which matches any of the characters in the character set.

Valid command is:

```
sudo sed -i '/:OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW - \[0:0\]/a \
-A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53248 -j ACCEPT \
-A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 50825 -j ACCEPT \
-A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20048 -j ACCEPT \
-A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT \
-A OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT' /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

EDIT 2:
If your `sed` supports `r` command (read from filename), you can save the `iptables` rules to `add_rules.txt`. Then you can add it to existing rules.

```
sed -i '/:OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW - \[0:0\]/r add_rules.txt' /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```